# Searching a HashMap for multiple values

Tags: java, loops, search, arraylist, hashmap

I am storing a contact list as a HashMap of type "Person", and want to have a search feature where I can search the HashMap and then return all people of the first name "John" and who live in the USA, for example. My idea is to just create an ArrayList of Person and loop through add each value as such:

```
  Map<Person, Person> hm = new HashMap<Person, Person>();
  ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

  Enumeration num= hm.keys();
  String name = "John";
  String location = "USA"; 

  while (num.hasMoreElements()) {
         Person person = (Person) num.nextElement();

         if(person.name.equals(name) && person.location.equals(location))
         {
            result.add(person);
         }
```

I was just wondering if this would work okay or if there is some better way of doing this that I've overlooked.

Thanks

Comment: You're using a `Map<Person, Person>` but it looks like you really should be using `Set<Person>`. You can read more at: http://java67.blogspot.com.au/2013/01/difference-between-set-list-and-map-in-java.html

Answer (score 1):

Unless you actually need to map `Person` objects I would suggest you use a `Set` rather than a `Map`:

```
Set<Person> people = new HashSet<Person>();
```

Java 8 gives you a nice way of creating a filtered set:

```
Set<Person> subset = people.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getName().equals(name))
    .filter(p -> p.getLocation().equals(location))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

If you want certain predefined search criteria then you can create these as methods:

```
class Person {
    public static Predicate<Person> hasNameAndLocation(String name, Location location) {
        return person -> person.name.equals(name) && person.location.equals(location);
    }
}
```

That makes your filtering code much nicer and avoids the use of getters:

```
.filter(Person.hasNameAndLocation("Fred", Country.USA))
```

If you need very high performance (likely only necessary for millions of items or thousands of searches a second) then the solution is to have separate maps to make predefined searches very fast:

```
Map<String, Set<Person>> nameMap;
Map<Location, Set<Person>> locationMap;

Set<Person> subset = nameMap.get("Fred")
    .filter(locationMap.get(Country.USA)::contains))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

This can be very fast but makes your code much more complicated as you have multiple collections to keep up to date. Don't do this unless you have significant performance requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `Enumerable`, I would suggest your use the `for` syntax on the keys.

```
   for ( Person person : hm.keys() )
   {
       // Your if statement goes here
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You really want:

```
Set<Person> hm = new HashSet<Person>();
for(Person person: hm)
{
    // your logic here
}
```

If for some reason you're still dead set on a map, iterate through it like this:

```
for(Map.entry<Person, Person> entry: hm.entrySet())
{
    // use entry.getKey() and entry.getValue()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no structural better solution since a HashMap contains its keys in an arbitrary, opaque order that can not be used by any algorithm not exactly knowing the internals. Therefore there is no clean way around iterating through all elements (keys).

The stylistic improvement I'd also suggest has already been shown be @WW.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Map<String, Integer> myMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
    List<Entry<String, Integer>> listOfEntries = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>(myMap.entrySet());

     for(int i=0;i<listOfEntries.size();i++){
//listOfEntries.get(0).getValue(), put your condition for comparison   
            if(listOfEntries.get(0).getValue()==listOfEntries.get(i).getValue()){
                        System.out.println(listOfEntries.get(i));
                    }
                }
```